# Best approach for well-known rows in user-customizable table?

Tags: core-data, database-design

I write database applications for a living that the end user can customize.

Frequently, this means that--leaving the database aside for a moment--some of my notional entity types have a universe or domain that is infinite.

Take name types.  You could have a first name, last name, married name, legal name, salutation name, and so on.  I am not going to put an upper bound on this universe.

But I do need to find and use certain well-known name types.  Let's say display name and sort name, just to keep it simple.

I would also like to be able to query for all name types (i.e. the whole universe) and have my well-known name types returned as well.

There are several strategies for accomplishing this within a database:

1. Have one name_type table with an id column and a code column.  ID values less than a certain amount are "reserved" for use by the system; ID values higher than this are deemed to be user types.
2. Add a column to the id/code pair that is some representation of a boolean or an int type that indicates what type of row this is (e.g. user-defined or system).  Same thing, really; just uses another column to explicitly break out the information instead of overloading it in the id.
3. Have two tables with perhaps a naming convention: name_type and name_type_system.  It is understood or enforced that name_type_system is off-limits to users; name_type is their domain.  Queries do a UNION across these tables and applications just "know" to never update the system table.

What strategies do people use?  Any war stories?  Any particular reasons to pick one over the other?  Huge pitfalls I'm not seeing?

Best,
Laird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of your three ideas the first is often called a Magic Number, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming), and is a Bad Thing because any code that doesn't "know" about it can make mistakes.  Plus you end up over time realizing, "oops, I need to push the minimum value higher, need to resequence 10,000 existing rows."  headaches, headaches.

After that, either of the other two works.    But the third one lets you use the DB server to deny insert/update/delete access to the account used by end-users, simplifying code.

The way to decide between option 2 and 3 is to ask, are they really 2 separate things?  If they are, they will tend to have different security, different operations are performed on them, one is modified by upgrades, the other is not, etc.  If they really are two different things, they go in two tables.  If they are two flavors of one thing that are almost always treated the same, they go in one table with a "type" flag, option 2.

Comment: Thanks; excellent answer. In my case option 2 is the way to go, following this logic.